# も Particle before です

Tags: particles, particle-も

I came across a post on this site saying that :

> 私もです

For example was not correct grammatically, and that instead, we had to use

> 私でもある。

I'm very confused now even though I know 私もです is used a lot, I don't know wether it's correct or not.

Saying 私でもある makes me feel like I'm writing a book or a poem because of である. And on the other hand 私もです sounds very natural and correct to me because です is basically a contraction of であります, so we could say でもあります but not something like でもす so i feel like it's obvious that も comes before です.

So to me でもある is used just like である, but with the particle も added meaning "also, too", so mostly used in writing.
And もです is used like です, in everydays life just to express a simple "Me too"

But after seeing those posts saying that もです is grammatically not correct, I wondered if もである with the particle も being before である is correct.

Comment: I think 私もです is usually short for 私も(そう)です.

Comment: Whoever said 私もです was ungrammatical was wrong.

Comment: My teacher used to say that putting any particle before です was wrong. Then I told her about も and の and now she doesn't say that anymore. (Read: People can be wrong and following grammar "rules" is not always right.)

Comment: @Eric The truth is almost any particle (read postposition) before です is **valid**. 私もです, 私からです, 私にだけです, 私とやらまでです etc.

Answer (score 3):

When talking casually, 私も is extremely common and, depending on the situation, often means "me too".

I would like to see the full post you mentioned, but I'd guess that whoever wrote 私もです was just finding a polite way to say 私も. Either way, 私もですis not wrong.